# Unit testing image tag with image object

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

i have following reactjs code snippet:

```
import lionIcon from 'assets/images/lion.svg';
import dogIcon from 'assets/images/dog.svg';

<img
    className="animal-btn-img"
    src={isLion ? lionIcon : dogIcon}
  />
```

how do i unit test that based on 'isLion' prop, appropriate animal object is set on the img tag.?

```
let img = wrapper.find('.animal-btn-img');
console.log(img.prop('src'));
```

the above console.log returns only empty object as {}

Answer (score 1):

try `shallow` from `enzyme`, it worked well for me

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import Testor from '../components/Testor'

import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });


it('should see image source', () => {
    const container = shallow(<Testor/>)
    expect(container.find('img').props().src).toEqual('http://google.com/')
})
```